# Was this the first use of the F-word in Star Trek?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-picard

In Series 1 Episode 2 of *Picard*, Admiral Clancey accuses Admiral Picard of 'f***ing hubris'. Is this the first use of the F-word in TV/movie Star Trek?

Comment: It's the first one *I'm* aware of, and I've watched all the series and movies at least once.  But that's not an "official" answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the strongest profanity used in a Star Trek show?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/171709/what-is-the-strongest-profanity-used-in-a-star-trek-show)

Comment: Nope. It was used previously in Star Trek: Discovery, see: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/171709/what-is-the-strongest-profanity-used-in-a-star-trek-show

Comment: Streaming services have less restrictions on profanity and such than networks have.

Comment: In a Voyager episode the holodeck character Leonardo da Vinci says the Italian "Che cazzo" which apparently translates into English as "What the fuck?"

Comment: Just another nail in the star trek coffin imo.